# Nginx vhost inherits ssl_certificate* directives from default block?

Tags: ssl, nginx, virtualhost

Here's what I'm ultimately trying to do, for full disclosure: I am trying to set up TLS on multiple vhosts using a single certificate with SNI: one vhost for the apex, and another for a separate host. That is, I want to serve `https://example.com` and `https://host.example.com` using the same certificate. Both hosts resolve to the same IPv4 address.

I'm having trouble understanding what Nginx is doing with `ssl_certificate*` directives. Those directives are only defined in the default server block, but are being "picked up" in another block anyway.

I started with a default server block to 404.

```
server {
  return 404;
}
```

As expected,

```
$ curl --head http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
[...]
```

Then I created the first example.com block to redirect http to https on the apex:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com;
}
```

And this works too:

```
$ curl --head http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
[...]
Location: https://example.com

$ curl --head http://host.example.com
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
[...]
```

Then I configured TLS on the apex:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate [...];
  ssl_certificate_key [...];
  server_name example.com;
}
```

So far, so good: http redirects to https, and https works.

```
$ curl --head http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
[...]
Location: https://example.com

$ openssl s_client -connect example.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
[...]
---
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Then I ran into a brief snag. I hadn't yet said a word about `host.example.com`, and yet when I tried to connect over TLS:

```
$ curl --head http://host.example.com
HTP/1.1 404 Not Found
[...]

$ openssl s_client -connect host.example.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
[...]
---
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: host.example.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[... content from example.com...]
```

The default block is responding to `http://host.example.com`, as it should. But `https://host.example.com` is matching the server block for `https://example.com`.

So after a bit of head scratching, I realized I needed *two* default blocks: one for each port.

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate [...];
  ssl_certificate_key [...];
  return 404;
}
```

Confirming this is what I needed:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect host.example.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
[...]
---
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: host.example.com

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
[...]
```

But then I realized something. And here is where my confusion starts. I shouldn't be able to, and don't understand why I was able to, connect to example.com:443 (or host.example.com:443) over TLS, *at all*.

When I created the second default server for port 443, I *removed* the `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` directives from the server block for https://example.com. They are only defined in the default server block.

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate [...];
  ssl_certificate_key [...];
  return 404;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;
  # No ssl_certificate* directives!
}
```

And yet, somehow, the certificate I defined in the *default* server block ends up being used when I try to connect to https://example.com:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect example.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
[...]
---
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[...]
```

And I also confirmed that visiting the url `https://example.com` in a browser serves up an actual page.

So, the configuration for https://example.com seems to be *inheriting* the settings for TLS from the default block, but then *applying* the rest of the settings from the server block that matches. Is that what's happening? I've tried searching on most of the matrix of keywords I can think of: "nginx", "tls", "ssl", "vhost", "default server block", "inherits", "inheritance"; but I can't find anything, and the documentation seems to be silent. It's probably written somewhere, but I'm not looking in the right place.

ADDED:

Full configuration, which is a basic Debian install, mostly unchanged from the package defaults.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
# above line loads:
# ngx_http_auth_pam_module, ngx_http_geoip_module, ngx_http_image_filter_module, ngx_http_xslt_filter_module, ngx_mail_module, ngx_stream_module

events {
  worker_connections 768;
}

http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  server_tokens off;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types; # nothing unusual in here
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # drop SSLv3
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf; # empty directory, includes nothing
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*; # includes single file which defines server blocks as above
}
```

And that's basically it.

EDIT AGAIN:

Here is the full server config file, all in one place.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  return 404;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate [...];
  ssl_certificate_key [...];
  return 404;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;
  root /srv/www/example.com;
  index index.html;
}
```

With this configuration, visiting https://example.com works, and uses the certificate configured in the default server block. Why?

Comment: Can you post the entire config file as it stands today?

Comment: Sorry for the multiple replies. I added the contents of nginx.conf to the bottom of my post. It's mostly unchanged from the default conf installed by Debian.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the expected behavior according to the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#name_based_https_servers):

> The SSL connection is established before the browser sends an HTTP
>   request and nginx does not know the name of the requested server.
>   Therefore, it may only offer the default server’s certificate.

The solution would be to use [different IPs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate):

> It should be kept in mind that due to the HTTPS protocol limitations
>   virtual servers should listen on different IP addresses otherwise the
>   first server’s certificate will be issued for the second site.